# Regex grouping: numbers separated by white spaces

Tags: regex, grouping

A server sends me some string representing some shapes.

```
<RECTANGLE> 157 20 225 99 </RECTANGLE>
<CIRCLE> 282 301 7 </CIRCLE>
```

Let's take the rectangle one.

```
<RECTANGLE> 157 20 225 99 </RECTANGLE>
```

Now i need to get these groups when I exec my regex:

```
myArray[0] = "<RECTANGLE> 157 20 225 99 </RECTANGLE>"
myArray[1] = "RECTANGLE"
myArray[2] = " 157 "
myArray[3] = " 20 "
myArray[4] = " 225 "
myArray[5] = " 99 "
```

But with my current regex:

```
<(.*?)>( \S+ )+</\1>
```

it returns me:

```
null
```

And if I use this input:

```
<SQUARE> 55465 </SQUARE>
```

I only get:

```
myArray[0] = "<SQUARE> 55465 </SQUARE>"
myArray[1] = "SQUARE"
myArray[2] = " 55465 "
```

So it only works when there is only one (white space)number(whitespace) in the string.

Can someone help to correct my regex so it get all (white space)number(whitespace) in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot capture a variable number elements into capture groups, because they would overwrite each other.

```
Not working: <(.*?)>\s*(?:(\d+)\s*)*</\1>
```

The second capture group `(\d+)` captures a number into \2, but repeating the matching by the outer group will overwrite \2 with subsequent numbers so in the end \2 will contain the last matched number.

You must do this in two steps. First extract the whole set of numbers and then separately extract the numbers from that.

```
Intermediate step: <(.*?)>\s*(\d+\s*)*</\1>
```

which will get something like "157 20 225 99 " into \2 which you can then split on spaces to get the individual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

space is `\040`
I recommend u use explode/split/etc because its better than regex on this example

Comment: I changed a bit the regex to <(.*?)>( \S+)+ </\1> and now I obtain the last one. I read that unless it's in .net, the group gets overriden. Is that also the case in java?, and if not, using a regex is a criteria of the work i have to do, so I can't use string.split().